# How do I individually separate the shapes on this sandal design?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drawing

I have made the outline for a shoe and i wish to separate the top tongue rectangle from the sole of the shoe. I am not sure how to individually separate each intersection of the shape.

[image: The square displays the editing area I wish to use and separate from the sole of the shoecdesign.]

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the image twice and put each one on a new layer then delete / erase / cutout the bits you don't need. There are a few ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the construction of your paths but I think this one can make it:

select the objects (not the dashed line), and go to **Pathfinder** Panel and hit **Trim**.

See the picture below:

[image]